# Listview and close form not delete directory

Tags: vb.net, listview, directory

My listview codes:

```
 Const IMAGE_DIRECTORY As String = "outfile"
    Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(IMAGE_DIRECTORY)
    Dim max_length, i As Integer
    Dim fname As String
    Dim pname As String
    Dim myImage As Image
    'Set the ColorDepth and ImageSize properties of imageList1.
    ImageList1.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit
    ImageList1.ImageSize = New System.Drawing.Size(106, 150)
    max_length = files.Length - 1
    'Add images to imageList1.
    For i = 0 To max_length
        pname = Path.GetFullPath(files(i))
        myImage = Image.FromFile(pname)
        ImageList1.Images.Add(myImage)
        myImage = Nothing
    Next
    pname = Nothing
    'ListView1.View = View.LargeIcon
    ListView1.LargeImageList = ImageList1
    For i = 0 To files.Length - 1
        fname = Path.GetFileName(files(i))
        Dim listViewItem1 As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem(fname, i)
        'Add listViewItem1 and listViewItem2.
        ListView1.Items.AddRange(New ListViewItem() {listViewItem1})
        listViewItem1 = Nothing
    Next
    'Me.Controls.AddRange(New Control() {listView1})
    ListView1.Items(0).Selected = True
    ListView1.Select()
```

---

Exit command button and remove files error now:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.PictureBox2.Image.Dispose()
    Me.ImageList1.Dispose()
    Me.PictureBox2.Image.Dispose()
    Me.Dispose()
    Me.Close()

End Sub
```

---

Exit form and remove directory outfile error :

> System.IO.IOException was unhandled
>      HRESULT = -2147024864
>      Message = The process is being used by another process 'Seite0.Jpg' can not access the file.
>      Source = mscorlib

What is the code problem ?

Comment: your code seems to have nothing to do with the question. there is nothing there related to closing a form or deleting a file

Comment: exit button and closed form, not remove files.

Comment: Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.PictureBox2.Image.Dispose()
        Me.ImageList1.Dispose()
        Me.PictureBox2.Image.Dispose()
        Me.Dispose()
        Me.Close()

    End Sub

Comment: there is still nothing there related to deleting a directory; nor is it clear what line you are getting the error on

Comment: not remove directory, The unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll 

Additional information: The process is being used by another process 'C: \ Users \ Axelle \ Documents \ Visual Studio 2013 \ Projects \ is \ bin \ Debug \ outfile \ Seite0.Jpg' can not access the file.